# Using a thumbnail image, how do I change main picture to thumbnail image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, onhover

I am trying to use Javascript to change a picture with on-hover. I have a thumbnail image and when the user hovers on top, the big picture will then change, depending on what thumbnail is being hovered over.

This is the HTML I have used.

```
<img onmouseover="showT(0)" src="pictures/278 Edit 10-8-11 2312.jpg" 
                    height="75" width="75" >
            <a href="#" onmouseover="showT(0)">pic 1</a>
            <a href="#" onmouseover="showT(1)">pic 2</a>
            <a href="#" onmouseover="showT(2)">pic 3</a>
```

This is the java script placed in header.

```
    <!-- onhover mouse for thumbNail -->
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript"> 
function showT(q){ 
document.getElementById('ima').setAttribute('src','0'+q+'.jpg') 
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Does your `showT()` function get called? Do you get any errors in the Javascript console? Can you make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) with a self-contained example?

Comment: Also, I believe the `language="JavaScript"` attribute is deprecated, and the MIME type one should be all lowercase: `type="text/javascript"`.

Comment: I have no errors. In internet Explorer the script works, it just does not want to load up the new image. In FireFox it does not work at all.

Comment: @ stefan, id="ima" is in the picture getting change  <!-- picture changes based onHover javascript -->
             <img id="ima" src="pictures/3inLarge.jpg" 
                  height="200" width="175" alt="3 inch Binder" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it using jQuery:

HTML:

```
<img src="my-initial-picture.jpg" alt="Any alternative text" id="bigpic" />
<!-- store the id of the picture that should be displayed in a data-* attribute -->
<a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-index="0">pic 1</a>
<a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-index="1">pic 2</a>
<a href="#" class="thumbnail" data-index="2">pic 3</a>
```

JS (in `<head></head>`):

```
<script>
/* when mouse is over any HTML element that has a "thumbnail" class */
$(".thumbnail").mouseover(function() {
    /* change the "src" attribute of the element whose id is "bigpic" */
    /* the .data() method will get the picture id stored in the data-* attribute */
    $("#bigpic").attr("src", "0" + $(this).data("index") + ".jpg");
});
</script>
```

You can add jQuery using the repo of Google (in `<head></head>`):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I haven't got into jQuery that much, what does what exactly?

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought too, that's why I commented the code :) Don't hesitate if you need some more help. Once you'll get familiar with jQuery, you'll never write any native JS anymore :)

Comment: If I wrap the thumbnail images into a <div> tag would I still have to add the id="thumbnail" to each image? Or would it be able to tell?

Comment: It is not an id but a class. An id must be unique in your HTML document. If you do so, put an id on your div, like `<div id="thumbnail-wrapper">` and use `$("#thumbnail-wrapper a").mouseover` instead of `$(".thumbnail").mouseover`.

Comment: Alright, now this is completely screwing with my mind... `.attr("src", "0" + $(this).data("index") + ".jpg");`

Comment: `$(this).data("index")` returns the number you stored in the HTML attribute `data-index` in every `<a>` tag. `.attr("src", "any value")` changes the HTML attribute "src" with the new value you specified. `$(this)` is the current object you're using in the method, i.e. the HTML `<a>` tags. If you never tried jQuery and you have *no time to learn* (shame on you! :) ), it's probably a bit rough for you. You can also use @JonathanPayne solution, but with all due respect, his solution isn't very clean :)

Comment: `$("#thumbnail-wrapper a").mouseover(function() {
    $("#bigpic").attr("src", "0" + $(this).data("index") + ".jpg");
});` is the script but it is not working... Here the is the thumbnail image `class="thumbnail" data-index="0"` I really wouldn't mind learning this for future websites.

Answer (score 3):

This works.. I had to add "ima" to the id of image, close the image tag. Also, i'm passing in the location of the image, rather than an index, it's simple enough to change that.

Hope this helps, cheers.

```
<img id="ima" src="http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png" height="75" width="75"/>

<a href="#" onmouseover="showT( 'http://www.google.com/logos/2012/cossington_smith-12-hp.jpg' )">pic 1</a>
<a href="#" onmouseover="showT( 'http://www.google.com/logos/2012/earthday12-hp.jpg' )">pic 2</a>
<a href="#" onmouseover="showT( 'http://www.google.com/logos/2012/Friedrich_Frobel-2012-hp.jpg' )">pic 3</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showT( image )
    {
         document.getElementById( 'ima' ).setAttribute('src',image ) 
    }
</script>
​
```